# Why doesn't steam work on wine?

Tags: 11.10, steam

I just installed steam on Ubuntu 11.10 and it will start and everything, but as soon as I click on "Store" it crashes. Please help me as soon as you can. Are there extra things that I need to do with Wine to make this work? For those of you who may have installed Wine, what did you do. I am SO unsure why this is happening.

Comment: Wine and Steam both change far too frequently for a QA post here that will do anybody any good after today. I suggest you read the [Steam page on AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444) which is constantly updated and has a good walkthrough.

Answer (score 1):

Steam does work on wine, although there are a few things that needs to be done to make it run flawlessly, such as installing microsoft core-fonts and a few library replacements. The easiest method of installing wine is using winetricks. Uninstall Steam first, then install winetricks, start winetricks and pick Steam for the installation. Note that apps installed through winetricks are installed into a prefixed environment, therefore if you want to start Steam.exe through command line for whatever reason, you must set the WINEPREFIX environment variable (otherwise it will be run in wine's default environment). Steam can install a shortcut in the Desktop and Start Menu, and wine is smart enough to add WINEPREFIX to those shortcuts, so they're the best option to start a prefixed app.